# programmatically get base url from inside google app engine endpoint method

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am creating a Google Appengine endpoint api. In one of the endpoint methods, I need to detect the base url. How might I do that in Java?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation, you can pass an injected type into your API Methods. For e.g. you could inject the HTTPServletRequest object into your API Method. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#injected_types

Once you have the Request object, you can then get the base url as needed. For e.g.

```
StringBuffer url = req.getRequestURL();
String uri = req.getRequestURI();
String ctx = req.getContextPath();
String base = url.substring(0, url.length() - uri.length() + ctx.length()) + "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Necessary Imports

```
import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalEnvironment;
import com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
```

Retrieve current hostname (base url)

```
ApiProxy.Environment proxyEnvironment = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment();
Map<String, Object> attributes = proxyEnvironment.getAttributes();
String hostname = (String) attributes.get(LocalEnvironment.DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME);
```

Include version on current hostname (current version + base url)

```
String version = SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get();
if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    hostname = String.format("%s.%s", version , hostname );
}
```